# Is there a way to make the object move infinitely?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

Like if it had some kind of invisible propeller.

Thank you.

Comment: rigid body simulations by default have earth gravity (but you can change it) so a falling object will fall forever, until stopped, reversing G, it will fall upwards. to make it really "fly", you need either to "propel" it or animate it, imho.

Comment: do you need it as an active rigid body object? If not, just animate it.

Comment: I need it, that's the problem.